# Setting variable to React component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This code uses React version 0.14.

I am trying to set a var to a react component and return it. My eventual goal is to use a switch to assign different components based on some props. This is the part of my render statement not working:

```
var inputNumber = <InputNumber displayText={this.props.data.DisplayText} />;
return (
    {inputNumber}
);
```

This replacement code evaluates fine:

```
return (
    <InputNumber displayText={this.props.data.DisplayText}/>
);
```

This is the error message I get (InputDataItem is the component the above snippet is from):

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: InputDataItem.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

Clearly I have a gap in my syntax understanding.

I based my assumption on this working off of this part of the React documentation (4th code example): https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
return (
  <div>
    {inputNumber}
  </div>
);
```

or simply:

```
return inputNumber;
```

Comment: I knew it'd be something simple. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

The `{...}` are only special inside JSX. In

```
return (
    {inputNumber}
);
```

there is no JSX. The `{...}` denote an *object literal*, even though it might not seem like one to you. What's new in ES2015 is something called *short object notation*, which allows you to omit the key. Your code is equivalent to

```
return (
    {inputNumber: inputNumber}
);
```

Either just return the `inputNumber` or put `{...}` inside JSX, as the other answer suggets.